# Hide shipping method when another available

Tags: shipping, ce-1.9.0.1, shipping-methods

In my Magento CE setup I have the WebShopApps Fastway couriers shipping method and I also have the Flat Rate Shipping Method on set to $0 for when the package either isn't valid for Fastway as it is to heavy or Fastway can't return a result for some reason, so the Flat Rate Method shows as "Contact us for a Shipping Quote".

My problem is that even when fastway returns options people are still choosing the "Contact us for a Shipping Quote $0" one and then I have to chase them to get them to pay the Fastway amount.

Is there some way to only show the Flat Rate Option if Fastway returns it's Error value (ie when it can't find a shipping amount) of "Please contact us for a shipping quote."

Comment: I think for paid shipping module you may contact it's vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping and method collectRates  where you have $result object with all rates. Toy can check this object and remove some methods / rates depending on your logic.